# Send "enter key" to python script from bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, python, python3

I am trying to automate my ubuntu setup with a bash script and got the following problem:

I want the script to automatically send a <kbd>enter</kbd> keystroke, when running `umake ide eclipse` (this installs eclipse ide from the terminal).

This is the standard output, when running from the terminal without a script:

```
$ umake ide eclipse
Choose installation path: /home/gn4i/.local/share/umake/ide/eclipse
<need to press enter>
Downloading and installing requirements
```

Normally I would do this with `echo | umake ide eclipse`, but I always get the following error

```
 $ echo | umake ide eclipse
Choose installation path: Choose installation path: ERROR: Unhandled exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/tools.py", line 158, in wrapper
    function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/ui/__init__.py", line 42, in display
    cls.currentUI._display(contentType)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/ui/cli/__init__.py", line 61, in _display
    contentType.run_callback(result=rlinput(contentType.content, contentType.default_input))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/ui/cli/__init__.py", line 41, in rlinput
    return input(prompt + " ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

How can I automate this installation?

Comment: Maybe `{echo ; sleep 5 ; } | umake ide eclipse` ? The error message is complaining about EOF so we keep the pipe open for another 5 seconds. Just a guess.

Comment: solved it with a screen approach. This runs in the background and i dont see the progress, but this is ok for me: `screen -d -m -S umake-eclipse` `screen -S umake-eclipse -p 0 -X stuff "umake ide eclipse\n\n"`

Comment: @icarus: Your solution does not work. `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'` It also does not work, when I replace the curly braces with round braces.

Comment: @icarus, you need a space between the opening brace and "echo"

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer, uloco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solved it with a screen approach. 
This runs in the background and I don't see the progress, but this is ok for me

```
screen -d -m -S umake-eclipse
screen -S umake-eclipse -p 0 -X stuff "umake ide eclipse\n\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a very simplistic `expect` script:

```
spawn umake ide eclipse
expect "Choose installation path:" { sleep 1; send "\r" }
```

Running it:

```
$ expect -f script.expect
```

Answer (score 1):

@Kusalananda's answer won't work in practice as the execution of the `umake` command stops after the `send` command.

Here's an extended, working solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn umake ide eclipse
expect "Choose installation path:" { send "\r" }
interact
```